# Generate landscape pdf using Flying Saucer?

Tags: html, css, flying-saucer

I am using a flying saucer to generate pdf file. I want to the first page and the second page is in landscape mode and the rest is in portrait mode. So, I do this:

```
@page {
    margin-top: 3.3cm;
    margin-left: 2cm;
    margin-right: 2cm;
    margin-bottom: 3.3cm;
    size: A4 portrait;
    height: 21cm; width: 28.6cm
}

@page land { size: a4 landscape;}
.landscapePage { page:land; height: 21cm; width: 28.6cm}



<div class="page-break landscapePage">
 page 1
</div>

<div class="page-break landscapePage">
 page 2
</div>
```

but it automatically creates 2 blank pages in the first of pdf file?
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the culprit is the `height` property in the landscape pages.

The height (21cm) plus the margin (2*3.3cm) are bigger than the available height on the (real) page, and flying-saucer add a additional page to handle the content.

The simplest way to make it work is to remove the properties about size. The only one that is needed is the width on the landscape page, to make sure the div will use the full page width.

```
    .page-break{page-break-before: always}
    @page {
        margin-top: 3.3cm;
        margin-left: 2cm;
        margin-right: 2cm;
        margin-bottom: 3.3cm;
        size: A4 portrait;
    }

    @page land { size: a4 landscape;}
    .landscapePage { page:land; width:25.3cm}
```